# Ударение в слове "капнометрия"

Tags: орфоэпия, терминология

Где ставится ударение в слове **капнометрия**?

Answer (score 2):

Медики ставят ударение (где надо и где не надо) исключительно на *и*: капнограф**и**я.

[Капнография микропотока](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLZCxaQHBVU) - можно послушать.

В словарях не фиксируется, но вот результат поиска по [*-метрии:*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=*%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F&all=x)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В русско-французском медицинском словаре стоит ударение на слоге -метр- капномЕтрия
 https://classes.ru/all-french/dictionary-french-russian-med-term-7657.htm

А как наши медики произносят - кто их знает, у них профессионализмы все на -ия