# О постановке ударения — ГДЕ или КУДА?

Tags: грамотная-речь, наречия, выбор-варианта

Сомнения возникли после правки вот этого вопроса: **[Ударение в слове "капнометрия"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/444134/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F)**.

Первоначально он звучал так: ***Куда*** ставится ударение в слове "капнометрия"?
Чисто интуитивно я исправила **куда** на **где**. А правильно ли я сделала?

*КУДА ставится ударение?* *ГДЕ ставится ударение?*
Какой из вариантов предпочтителен?

Answer (score 1):

Употребляются оба варианта.

Предпочтительнее употреблять *Куда* ставить (ставится) ударение? (например, в слове пломбировать), имея в виду *на какой слог* (**вин. п**.), но *Где должно стоять ударение в слове пломбировать?*, *На каком слоге?*(предл. п.)

Но *ставить где?* тоже нормативно, в отличие от сочетаемости с глаголом *стоять*, стоять требует только предложного падежа.

**Ставить *кого? что?  куда?* где? стоит *где*?**

Comment: Согласен, что допустимы оба варианта. Но по поводу предпочтений есть сомнения. Почему-то в подавляющем большинстве специализированных книг, до которых дотягивается Гугл, употребляется "где". Интуитивно, мне этот вариант тоже более привычен.

Comment: Вероятно, предпочтения здесь зависят от привычки каждого, а вот по логике мы спрашиваем: падает куда? ставим куда?-  на слог, а стоит где? - на слоге. Первый вариант - процесс, движение куда-то, а второе - итог процесса, движения (где оно уже стоит.)

Comment: В книгах вообще избегают таких фраз, а на сайтах я чаще вижу как раз куда? http://completerepair.ru/kuda-stavitsya-udarenie
("Куда ставится ударение? Ударение в русском языке нефиксированное, то есть оно не падает всегда на какой-то определенный слог"вин.п.), 
bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/...
https://znanija.com/task/19130870  
http://sldi.ru/kuda-stavitsya-udarenie-v-slove-plombirovat
http://otvet.expert/kuda-stavitsya-udarenie-v-slove-prinyalsya-1275482